# Paypal api: I keep getting "Authentication failed. API credentials are incorrect."

Tags: jquery, paypal

I am trying to `POST` a request to:

```
https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/Pay
```

Using JQuery mobile.
I've tried doing it in Postman and everything worked fine, received the keys and everything I need. However using the Ajax, it returns me an error:

```
Authentication failed. API credentials are incorrect.
```

And I am using the same exact headers (appid, userid, password, signature and data formats)
Here is my method that posts the request:

```
function sendPayment(amount){
$.ajax({
    method:'POST',
    dataType: "jsonp",
    url:"https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/Pay",
    headers:{
        "X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID" : "APP-80W284485P519543T",
        "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID" : "mysandboxemail.gmail.com",
        "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD" : "mysandboxpass",
        "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE" : "mysandboxsignature",
        "X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT" : "JSON",
        "X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT" : "JSON"
    },
    data:JSON.stringify({
        "actionType":"PAY",
        "currencyCode":"USD",
        "receiverList":{"receiver":[{
            "amount":"1.0",
            "email":"myreceiveremail@gmail.com"}]
        },
        "returnUrl":"http://Payment-Success-URL",
        "cancelUrl":"http://Payment-Cancel-URL",
        "requestEnvelope":{
            "errorLanguage":"en_US",
            "detailLevel":"ReturnAll"
        }
    }),
    success:function(data, status, xhr){
        console.log(data);
    },
    error:function(data){
        console.log(data);
    },
    timeout: 3000
});
}
```

Any ideas on what did I do wrong?
(I am using sandbox of course)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So we've discovered that JQuery adds something else to the headers or something therefore it was messing up the request.
So instead of using $.ajax methods of Jquery, use the old fashioned way:

```
var toSend={
    "actionType": "PAY",
    "currencyCode": "USD",
    "receiverList": {
        "receiver": [{
            "amount": 1.2,
            "email": "killer123@gmail.com"
        }]
    },
    "returnUrl": "http://google.com",
    "cancelUrl": "http://yahoo.com",
    "requestEnvelope": {
        "errorLanguage": "en_US",
        "detailLevel":'ReturnAll'
    }
};


var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', "https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/Pay", true);    // plug-in desired URL
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
        if (xhr.status == 200) {
            alert('Success: ' + xhr.responseText);  // the response json here
            alert(JSON.stringify(xhr)); //for debugging

        } else {
            alert('Error submitting image: ' + xhr.status);
            alert(JSON.stringify(xhr));

        }
    }
};
//form.append('file', dataUrl);
xhr.setRequestHeader( "X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID", "APP-coolioApp");
xhr.setRequestHeader( "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID", "senderman.gmail.com");
xhr.setRequestHeader( "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD", "supersecretpass");
xhr.setRequestHeader( "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE", "supersecrensignature-asdasd");
xhr.setRequestHeader( "X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT", "JSON");
xhr.setRequestHeader( "X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT", "JSON");
xhr.send(JSON.stringify(toSend));
```